# Colored Confusion Matrix omitting zero values

Tags: tables, color, matrices, gradient

I am trying to create a colored confusion matrix using macro for color gradients. Like the following one:

[image]

The final confusion matrix will be bigger, so I want to remove the zero values to improve the readability of the table. I cannot simply omit the zero from the cell, because of the macro that calculates the color gradient. Is there a way to omit the zeros maintaining the macro? 
Here the code I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% COLORED CM
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}

 %The min, mid and max values
\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{0.0}%
\newcommand*{\MidNumber}{0.2} %
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1.0}%

%Apply the gradient macro
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
        \ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(#1 - \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
            \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{green!\PercentColor!red}{#1}
        \else
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(\MidNumber - #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
            \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{white!\PercentColor!red}{#1}
        \fi
}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm} % box size
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

%% for rotation in table
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{R}[2]{%
    >{\adjustbox{angle=#1,lap=\width-(#2)}\bgroup}%
    l%
    <{\egroup}%
}
\newcommand*\rotz{\multicolumn{1}{R{0}{-1em}}}% no optional argument here, please! 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% END COLORED CM
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[t]
 \caption{The confusion matrix}
 \label{tab:CM}
    \centering
    \resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{ % to nicely resize the table in the text width

   \begin{tabular}{r*{6}{G}}
  \rotz{} & 
  \rotz{A} & 
  \rotz{B} & 
  \rotz{C} &
  \rotz{D} & 
  \rotz{E} \smallskip \\ 
   A        & 0.54  & 0     & 0.08  & 0.17  & 0     \\ 

   B        & 0     & 0.96  & 0     & 0     & 0     \\ 

   C        & 0.04  & 0.04  & 0.38  & 0.13  & 0     \\ 

   D        & 0.08  & 0     & 0.04  & 0.75  & 0     \\ 

   E        & 0     & 0.04  & 0     & 0     & 0.96  \\ 

  \end{tabular}%\par\bigskip
  }
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd never scale a table, but if you do, don't  do `}{!}{ % to ` do `}{!}{% to ` otherwise you force a scaled word-space to the left of the table,

Comment: can't you just add another if to your test, wrapping it all in `\ifdim #1 pt > 0pt ...\fi` so it does nothing on 0 ?

Comment: @AlessandroManzi Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{caption}

%The min, mid and max values
\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{0.0}%
\newcommand*{\MidNumber}{0.2} %
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1.0}%
\def\OmitZero#1.#2.#3!{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax     % #2 is empty -> no decimal
    #1%
  \else                  % #2 not empty -> decimal
    \ifnum#1=0           % we have 0.
      .#2%
    \else                % we have no 0.xx
      #1.#2%
    \fi
  \fi}

%Apply the gradient macro
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
    \ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(#1 - 
    \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
    \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{green!\PercentColor!red}{\OmitZero#1..!}
    \else
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(\MidNumber - 
    #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
    \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{white!\PercentColor!red}{\OmitZero#1..!}
    \fi
}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm} % box size
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

%% for rotation in table
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{R}[2]{%
    >{\adjustbox{angle=#1,lap=\width-(#2)}\bgroup}%
    l%
    <{\egroup}%
}
\newcommand*\rotz{\multicolumn{1}{R{0}{-1em}}}% no optional argument here, please! 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% END COLORED CM
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}


    \begin{table}[t]
        \caption{The confusion matrix}
        \label{tab:CM}
        \centering
        \resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{ % to nicely resize the table in the text width

            \begin{tabular}{r*{6}{G}}
                \rotz{} & 
                \rotz{A} & 
                \rotz{B} & 
                \rotz{C} &
                \rotz{D} & 
                \rotz{E} \smallskip \\ 
                A        & 0.54  & 0     & 0.08  & 0.17  & 0     \\ 

                B        & 0     & 0.96  & 0     & 0     & 0     \\ 

                C        & 0.04  & 0.04  & 0.38  & 0.13  & 0     \\ 

                D        & 0.08  & 0     & 0.04  & 0.75  & 0     \\ 

                E        & 0     & 0.04  & 0     & 0     & 0.96  \\ 

            \end{tabular}%\par\bigskip
        }
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want. I used also the advice of @DavidCarlisle